# Eclipse and its Completely Un-Mac-Like key bindings

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

**Update: for the CSV you can import into Eclipse, check this [Gist](http://gist.github.com/319104)** *[Ed: or not... looks like it's filled with ? marks where the key icons should be]*

**Discussion**

I've avoided Java development in OS X for some time now, only because Eclipse's UI feels extremely inconsistent with OS X's HIG. Not least of these are its fine-under-windows-but-totally-unacceptable-on-a-Mac default key bindings.

I'm in the process of fixing the key bindings I can in `Preferences -> Keys`, but a few are problematic.

Screen of the configuration pane if anyone has trouble finding it:
[image]

**Bindings I've changed so far:**
*[Note: if any of these seem strange, I'm trying to mimic Xcode where possible in the absence of an even broader standard shortcut on the Mac]*

```
      Name      |     Old Command  |  New Command  
----------------------------------------------------
Content Assist  | Ctrl-Space       | Escape 
Redo            | Cmd-Y            | Cmd-Shift-Z
Find Next       | Cmd-K            | Cmd-G
Find Previous   | Shift-Cmd-K      | Shift-Cmd-G
Backward History| Cmd-[            | *Unbind Command*
Forward History | Cmd-]            | *Unbind Command*
Properties      | Alt-Return       | Cmd-I
Debug           | Cmd-F11         | Cmd-Y
Run (in Windows)| Cmd-Shift-F11    | Cmd-R
Build Clean     | *Nothing*        | Cmd-Shift-K
```

**Bindings I need help with:**

- Indent/Outdent selection - Eclipse has these bound to tab & shift-tab, but they don't appear in the Keys dialog or any menu items (so Keyboards.prefpane can't change it eitehr).

I'll edit this question with a few more as I think of them. Because there isn't necessarily a single correct answer and this page may change over time, this is more appropriate as a community wiki page. The goal of this page will be to create a settings export that can be shared and reused by others.

Comment: Good question, but just for the record, Eclipse isn't just un-Mac-like. It's un-anything-else-like. For example, "Preferences" is in the "Window" menu on the Linux version, which is something I've never seen in any other app on any platform. It isn't even consistent with itself in many ways. eg: "Is the setting I'm looking for in General/Appearance/Java, or Java/Appearance?"

Comment: Fair point. It's its own little SWT-verse for that matter. Still, making it more Mac-like would improve my (and probably most new-guard software developers) quality of life, so hopefully people can use this thread to posit ideas of how to go about doing that. I'm still struggling to figure out how to override the default shift-tab behavior

Comment: Not necessarily defending the default eclipse shortcut keys, but I might suggest thinking about some of them more closely. The biggest example I can see is content assist. The ESC key is a definite break in your typing cadence which isn't a problem I have had with the Ctl Space default.

Comment: Hi Matt - This would have made no sense a few years ago, but with the critical mass of iPhone SDK devs/dabblers, I'm taking Xcode's lead with a lot of these shortcuts (hence Esc for content assist, Cmd-Y for debug, and Cmd-R for  run). I believe I've seen Esc elsewhere for the same purpose on Mac dev software and it's grown on me over time.  [Besides, most Mac folk I know use ctrl-space to trigger Quicksilver or their preferred launcher app]

Comment: Cmd+Space is used for switching IME on Mac OS X. Or spotlight. Fxxking Eclipse default key binding. Java is just a new virtual platform layer, not a cross-platform. They have no idea about melting down into underlying platform.

Comment: What's "Indent/Outdent selection"? Do you mean Shift Right/Left?

Comment: I have the same question – how can I make Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts work more like Xcode? Ideally if there is something that I can import into it.

Answer (score 2):

Another more Mac-like shortcut is setting the Properties commands shortcut to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an irritating key binding behavior just today. On Macs, the option key plus any standard key is always used to access extended characters — and this behavior has been consistent among all standard Mac apps for decades. I may be in a minority among coders, but I think given that everything supports UTF-8 nowadays, directly typing non-ASCII characters like ©, –, ¥, “, ”, €, and ¢ make for more readable and compact HTML than escaping everything (`&copy;`, `&ndash;`, `&yen;`, `&ldquo;`, `&rdquo;`, `&euro;`, and `&cent;`, respectively). Likewise with native words in other languages like français (`fran&ccedil;ais`) and español (`espa&ntilde;ol`), and typographically better contractions like they’re (`they&rsquo;re`).

Eclipse's key bindings irritatingly override that and prevent standard Mac keyboard behavior. You can return the normal Mac behavior here by going back into Eclipse's Keys prefs, sorting by Binding, and removing all bindings with ⌥ followed by a letter or number (but not those starting with ⌥⌘).